# About two 10-adic integer $x$ satisfies $x^2 = x$.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Consider about the 10-adic integer $x = \dots1787109376$ satisfies $x^2 = x$ and the 10-adic integer $y = \dots8212890625$ satisfying $y^2 = y$.

Define $a(n)$ as the $n$th digit of $x$:

$$a(0) = 6, \quad a(1) = 7, \quad a(2)= 3, \quad \dots $$

Define $b(n)$ as the $n$th digit of $y$:

$$b(0) = 5, \quad b(1) = 2, \quad b(3)= 6, \quad \dots $$

Define $c(n) = a(n) - b(n)$. (See [this](https://oeis.org/A075693).)

$$c(0) = 1, \quad c(1) = 5, \quad c(3) = -3, \quad \dots $$

Let $d(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n c(k).$

$$d(0) = 1, \quad d(1) = 6, \quad d(3) = 3, \quad \ldots, \\
\quad d(595) = 0, \quad d(596) = 1, \quad d(597) = 8, \quad \ldots $$

I calculated $d(n)$ until $n \leq 15000$ and made the following predictions, is this correct?

> **Prediction.** When $n > 597$, $d(n) < 0$.

P.S.

\begin{align*}
d( 1000) &= -181, \\
d( 2000) &= -105, \\
d( 3000) &= -387, \\
d( 4000) &= -121, \\
d( 5000) &= -453, \\
d( 6000) &= -393, \\
d( 7000) &= -523, \\
d( 8000) &= -539, \\
d( 9000) &= -689, \\
d(10000) &= -791, \\
d(11000) &= -635, \\
d(12000) &= -765, \\
d(13000) &= -779, \\
d(14000) &= -717, \\
d(15000) &= -1363.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you provide a graph or a few more sample values of $d$?

Comment: I add more sample values of d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the digits should behave like random numbers (and hence $d(n)$ would look like a sample path of a symmetric random walk), I am very skeptical about the idea that $d(n)$ will eventually assume a constant sign.

Indeed, using the first $100,000$ digits of $x$ and $y$, the graph of $d(n)$ turns out to be as follows:

[image: Graph of d(n)]

(After $n = 597$, the first time $d(n)$ becomes positive is $n = 37790$.)